# how to execute python script every 1556 seconds

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a python script that i want to execute after every 1556 seconds.

I how to run it if its in mins i.e. if I want to run it every 5 mins then I could do:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script/script.py
```

How do I set it up to run after every `1556 seconds`?

thanks

Comment: 1536 or 1556? You wrote two different things

Comment: 1536 seconds from when it last started, or 1536 seconds since it last ended?

Comment: sorry was a type... it should run after every 1556 seconds

Comment: You could incorporate a 56-second sleep in your script and run it every 25 minutes using cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1556 seconds would be approximately every 26 minutes so you can set up your cronjob to be like this :

```
*/26 * * * *
```

You have */26 in the minute's specifier - that means every minute but with a step of 26 (in other words, every At every 26th minute). Since cron does not go down to sub-minute resolutions, you will need to find another way.

If you want to perform the required literally at every 1556 seconds

```
*/25 * * * *  sleep 56 && python3 /path/to/script/script.py
```

also, you can Run your repeating task within a loop and it should do what you need:

```
#!/bin/env bash
while [ true ]; do
 sleep 1556
 # do what you need to here
done
```

Comment: Does `*/25` run only on `00, 25, 50` ?

Comment: This answer misunderstands how crontab lines are interpreted. `*/26` does not mean "run this job every 26 minutes". It means "run this job at minutes which are multiples of 26". So it will runt at 01:00, 01:26, 01:52, 02:00, 02:26, 00:52, etc. And the starting time of each job does not alter that starting time of the next job, so the only effect of `sleep 56` will be to delay the start time by 56 seconds, so that the second one will run at 01:00:56, 01:25:56, 01:50:56, etc.

Comment: Also, `while [ true ];` will work, but not for the reason you might think. It does not execute the `true` command. `[` is the `test` command, which gets executed; `true` is its argument, which is unevaluated; `[ true ]` succeeds because the test command with one argument succeeds exactly when the one argument is not empty. I suspect what you were looking for was `while true; do ...` which would execute `true` each time. A common idiom for this is `while :; do` because `:` is a no-op builtin which always succeeds. `while` precedes a *command* and continues as long as the command succeeds.

Comment: you are right about using the `:` or `true` builtins `while true` in bash (or dash or zsh for that matter), so i realized that there's no need for the [ ] characters.

Comment: @MahmoudOdeh: I'm right about the way cron interprets `*/26`, too. TIAS.

Answer (score 0):

1556 seconds, that's a weird number...

I would suggest use celery with ETA https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#dump-of-scheduled-eta-tasks

keep in mind...
"These are tasks with an ETA/countdown argument, not periodic tasks."